# Can a rogue wifi network install a CA certificate?

Tags: certificates, wifi, man-in-the-middle

Could an attacker create a false wifi network, then force (either via the user exploitation or other means) CA certificate install to the browser, allowing them to use something such as Burp Suite to MITM their browsing?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I have read this post, yet I was wondering how would an attacker get this CA cert on the device using a rogue wifi network.  Is it possible to make the AP prompt for a cert install or automatically do it itself?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to install a certificate through simply connecting to a Wi-Fi network. Now, it's possible to make a browser download a certificate through autodownload to somewhere in the Downloads folder, but that's just downloading the cert file and still requires you to manually install this certificate and enter an admin password.

That's about as far as it goes. Of course, sneakier ways exist, like getting you to download an executable that poses as a legitimate program but installs the cert, however that is going way out of the scope of the original question and just requires common sense to thwart.

Answer (score 0):

There are scenarios. There are a lot of variables:

- The implementation of wireless
- User training and awareness
- Hardware, software, vulnerabilities

If you can successfully deploy an evil twin you may be able to gain access to a vulnerable machine, escalate privileges, and install a trusted root ca certificate of your choice.

There are more protections for sites through certificate pinning and HSTS to prevent MiTM.

If you gain access to the machine as admin which is required to install a trusted root ca anyway, you can just view the traffic through tcp dump unencrypted without the warnings.

Comment: A tcp dump will not be able to decrypt a https session. That will only give you the bytes in the wire. You would need something like extracting the session keys from the browser that is performing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. The point is precisely that -while connecting through an untrusted network is quite common- *an attacker will not be able to install a CA into the client machine*.

Of course, there are cases where that *could* happen, eg. the machine additionally has a RDP service active with a trivial or no password on an Administrator account, but that would be a critical security hole on its own.

Answer (score -1):

[Cain and Able](http://www.oxid.it/ca_um/topics/apr-https.htm) has the ability to inject fake certificates into SSL sessions, that was recently controlled by [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing).